# Submitting celery jobs to an SGE queue

Tags: celery, sungridengine

I'm working on a cluster that uses SGE to manage jobs across the worker nodes. Is there a way to use the SGE queue as the broker in a way that will cooperate with other people submitting jobs through non-celery means. I currently use python-gridmap to submit python jobs to the SGE queue but I'd like to use the feature-set from Celery.

Would I need to make a new Broker, or Consumer, both?

Comment: I don't clearly get your question so my answer may not answer it... Have you looked into "qsub" and "qrsh" commands? It will schedule a job through SGE without celery.

Comment: I can easily submit jobs to the SGE queue using qsub or gridmap (and that's what I currently do). I want to use Celery features (like the Task decorator, chains, repeated running, etc) on a server with an SGE queue. I don't have administrative rights to start celery workers on the nodes so interacting with the SGE queue is my only option.